# PHPMyAdmin creating relationship beetween pages does not wor

Tags: phpmyadmin

Hi I am trying to create a relationship beetween two database tables in phpMyAdmin:

USERS

user_id , user_name , user_pwd

PROFILE

profile_id , profile_name , profile_email , profile address , user_id

After I click the create relation button I am asked to create a referenced key and I click on the USERS table user_id.
After that I am asked to set a foreign id and I select the profile user_id.
The next thing  a box appears with two buttons and a label that says Create Relation and the buttons OK and Cancel.I click on the OK button but nothing happens.I have tryed doing this a dozen times but with no succes.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The information surrounding the question is a bit weak, what storage engine is used etc. But I had a similar problem just now and the reason for it not working was because the referring key did not have an index. Usually this is handled automatically (I think phpMyAdmin is responsible for this but I do not know) but in some cases one will manually have to add the index to make it work.